# Java runs custom groovy code ，How to keep groovy safe?

Tags: java, groovy

How to prevent user input: `System.exit(0)` and Infinite loop

Eg:

```java
public class TestGroovy {
    public static ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException, NoSuchMethodException {
        TestGroovy testGroovy = new TestGroovy();
        testGroovy.runGroovy("    def executeMethod(){\n" +
                "        System.exit(0);\n" +
                "    }");
    }


    public void runGroovy(String groovyCode) throws ScriptException, NoSuchMethodException {
        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("groovy");
        engine.eval(groovyCode);
        Invocable invokeEngine = (Invocable) engine;
        invokeEngine.invokeFunction("executeMethod");
    }

}
```

If people input `System.exit(0)` or Infinite loop, It's too bad.

I want to block users from entering these.

Thanks ~

---

#### One answer I used this method ：

```java
public class MySecurityManager extends SecurityManager{

    @Override
    public void checkExit(int status) {
        throw new SecurityException();
    }

}
```

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("groovy");

        try {
            Map<String,Object> output=new HashMap<>();
            Bindings binding = engine.createBindings();
            binding.put("input",1);
            binding.put("output",output);

            String fact = "def executeMethod(){\n" +
                    "  \tSystem.exit(0);\n" +
                    "    output.put('your key','your value');\n" +
                    "    return output;\n" +
                    "}";
            engine.eval(fact,binding);
            Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;
            MySecurityManager secManager = new MySecurityManager();
            System.setSecurityManager(secManager);
            output  = (Map<String, Object>) inv.invokeFunction("executeMethod",null);
            System.out.println(output);
        } catch (SecurityException | ScriptException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
            System.out.println("can't input System.exit(0)");
        }
    }
```

Thanks~

Comment: You can't do that reliably. Don't let untrusted users run custom code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use separate threads to run user-defined code, I can suggest the following:

For `System.exit()` calls you can define and set your own [SecurityManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html). It has `checkExit()` method which tells if `System.exit` is possible. Override it and provide your logic. The drawback of this solution is that you have to make sure that your application always runs with `SecurityManager` enabled.

As to infinite loops or any other long-running code I can only suggest an external monitoring thread which in certain conditions (timeout or whatever) would just stop the thread. But this solution has a bunch of problems: you may run into resource leaks or deadlocks if the thread you have stopped owns an unclosed resource (open file, DB connection, etc.) or a lock. Interruption calls in this case won't work since the code may simply ignore them.

As an alternative solution, you can use a separate JVM to run user's code.

It's up to you to decide.

Answer (score 1):

I built my groovy execution sandbox based on [this article](https://melix.github.io/blog/2015/03/sandboxing.html).

`SecureASTCustomizer` and class/method whitelisting provides you with general solution to protect against many possible misuse of user custom scripts, not only against `System.exit(-1)`. Also, you don't need extra threads or JVM for that.

You can also inject Groovy's annotations to augment your code, like `@TimedInterrupt`.